# Unable to get qmake to cross compile correctly

Tags: android, c, clang, qmake

I am new to this build system, but I've spent dozens of hours trying to get qmake + clang to produce a working android binary. I would appreciate any help or advice. Here is as simple an example as I can come up with:

First, here is a working build command. It gives me a shared object that I can call from android (with Unity, using C# native interops):

```
C:\Users\deltav\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk2\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe ^
-target aarch64-none-linux-android21 -shared -v ^
-DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_ARM_MODE=arm -DANDROID ^
M:\simpleExample\simpleExample.c ^
-o M:\simpleExample\libsimpleExample.so
```

Here is the verbose output of running that command: https://pastebin.com/18HcnDYh

On the other hand, here is the simpleExample.pro file that is NOT giving me a good binary: https://pastebin.com/wxrx6Myc

Here is the qmake output for building in release mode: https://pastebin.com/KWavwrb7

As you will know, qmake uses a kit to execute the project. My kit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpjr0.jpg

---

The specific issue that has pushed me down this debugging path is from C# trying to load my shared object like this:

```
[DllImport("simpleExample")]
public static extern float getSpeedY();
```

The error that I get is this:

> "DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'simpleExample': The
> specified module could not be found."

Again, this error is not an issue if I just build from the CLI without qmake. I do not beleive this is a unity or C# error, as I worked the problem from that side first.

---

What I have tried so far:

1. I have used multiple ELF & DWARF tools to compare the ABIs of the generated binaries, which all told me the binaries were identical.
2. I tweaked and shaved down the clang calls that qmake generated until I got a vaild build command. Unfortunately I can't just replace qmake with the complile command because there are other projects that I need to apply this fix to.

---

QMake version 3.1
Ironically, CMake basically works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Looking at the clang linking call, you can see QMake 3.1 was adding "libc++shared" as a dependency. I'm not sure why, as this was a C project.
The equivalent CMake project did *not* do this.
Packaging libc++shared with my binary fixed the issue.